# This is more a matlab/math brain teaser than a question

Tags: math, matlab, linear-algebra

Here is the setup. No assumptions for the values I am using.

```
n=2; % dimension of vectors x and (square) matrix P 
r=2; % number of x vectors and P matrices
x1 = [3;5]
x2 = [9;6]
x = cat(2,x1,x2)
P1 = [6,11;15,-1]
P2 = [2,21;-2,3]
P(:,1)=P1(:)
P(:,2)=P2(:)
modePr = [-.4;16]
TransPr=[5.9,0.1;20.2,-4.8]

pred_modePr = TransPr'*modePr
MixPr = TransPr.*(modePr*(pred_modePr.^(-1))')
x0 = x*MixPr
```

Then it was time to apply the following formula to get `myP`
[image]

, where μij is MixPr. I used this code to get it:

```
myP=zeros(n*n,r);
Ptables(:,:,1)=P1;
Ptables(:,:,2)=P2;
for j=1:r
    for i = 1:r;
        temp = MixPr(i,j)*(Ptables(:,:,i) + ...
        (x(:,i)-x0(:,j))*(x(:,i)-x0(:,j))');
        myP(:,j)= myP(:,j) + temp(:);
    end
end
```

Some brilliant guy proposed this formula as another way to produce `myP`

```
for j=1:r 
  xk1=x(:,j); PP=xk1*xk1'; PP0(:,j)=PP(:);
  xk1=x0(:,j); PP=xk1*xk1'; PP1(:,j)=PP(:);
end
myP = (P+PP0)*MixPr-PP1
```

I tried to formulate the equality between the two methods and seems to be this one. To make things easier, I skipped the summation of matrix P in both methods .
[image]

where the first part denotes the formula that I used, and the second comes from his code snippet. Do you think this is an obvious equality? If yes, ignore all the above and just try to explain why. I could only start from the LHS, and after some algebra I think I proved it equals to the RHS. However I can't see how did he (or she) think of it in the first place.

Comment: Could you give a little more background on what exactly you're trying to do?

Comment: I think it can be dealt with independently from its concept (which actually has to do with multiple model Kalman filters). In the following link the first steps are described in more detail and the relevant formulas are given. There are some additional constraints there, about rows or columns that sum to 1, that are not necessary for the above equality to hold. http://lh6.ggpht.com/_QHi-vzRmFVU/S6kXEDyYn0I/AAAAAAAACqM/xW7XEbB8viI/MATLAB%20exam.jpg

Comment: I'm confused, you have a 2x4 matrix P, not a square matrix, and a bunch of separate lines with no apparent similarities (your formula uses Ptables which derives from P1 and P2, his uses x and x0.... If you want someone to check algebraic equivalence, I think you are asking on the wrong site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using E for expectation, the one dimensional version of your formula is the familiar:

```
Variance(X) = E((X-E(X))^2) = E(X^2) - E(X)^2
```

While the second form might be easier programming, I'd worry about ending up with a negative (or, in the multidimensional case, non positive definite) answer by using it, due to rounding error.